# Configuring log4j2.properties in Spring Boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, logging, log4j, log4j2

I am a newbie to Spring Boot. I have a running Spring Boot project. I want to use log4j2 (I am bound to use log4j2 itself because of project restrictions) to redirect all logs of different levels to a log file named 'test.log'

***Problem is - despite of all proper code included, I am not able to log INFO level logs in my test.log*** (I want to obviously log error and debug level logs also, but at least first INFO level logs should work fine)

--- I have excluded default logging and included log4j2 dependency in pom.xml :

```
<!-- Exclude Spring Boot's Default Logging -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Add Log4j2 Dependency -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.10.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.10.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

--- I have included logging.config in application.properties:

```
logging.file=logs/test.log
logging.level.*=INFO
logging.config=src/main/resources/log4j2.properties
```

--- My `log4j2.properties` looks as follows:

```
#status = error // do i need this actually??
dest = logs/test.log
name = PropertiesConfig

property.filename = logs/test.log

appender.console.type = Console
appender.console.name = STDOUT
appender.console.layout.type = PatternLayout
appender.console.layout.pattern = %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n

appender.rolling.type = RollingFile
appender.rolling.name = RollingFile
appender.rolling.fileName = logs/test.log
appender.rolling.filePattern = logs/test1-%d{MM-dd-yy-HH-mm-ss}-%i.log.gz
appender.rolling.layout.type = PatternLayout
appender.rolling.layout.pattern = %d %-5p %-17c{2} (%30F:%L) %3x - %m%n
appender.rolling.policies.type = Policies
appender.rolling.policies.time.type = TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy
appender.rolling.policies.time.interval = 2
appender.rolling.policies.time.modulate = true
appender.rolling.policies.size.type = SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy
appender.rolling.policies.size.size=10MB
appender.rolling.strategy.type = DefaultRolloverStrategy
appender.rolling.strategy.max = 5

logger.rolling.name = com.thp.clinic.allergiesConditions
logger.rolling.level = info
logger.rolling.additivity = false
logger.rolling.appenderRef.rolling.ref = RollingFile
#rootCategory=INFO,rolling,stdout
#logging.level.root=info

#rootLogger.level = debug  //do i necessarily need root Logger????
#rootLogger.appenderRefs = RollingFile
#rootLogger.appenderRef.stdout.ref = STDOUT

logger.rolling.name=org.hibernate.SQL
logger.rolling.level = debug
```

--- Also controller of my test API has following test log lines:

```
    //Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger //is included       
logger.debug("This is a debug message");
logger.info("This is an info message");
logger.warn("This is a warn message");
logger.error("This is an error message");
logger.fatal("This is a fatal message");
```

--- In my understanding, I have included all required things in code. But I am facing this issues - ***when I hit API, only hibernate debug loggers are being added to test.log; The five test loggers(or even other info level logs used) i have included in controller are not getting logged in test.log;***

The console looks like following(two of five loggers are being displayed on console, but here also INFO level logger is missing):

```
20:05:42.989 [http-nio-8000-exec-1] ERROR com.test.app.appController - This is an error message
20:05:42.994 [http-nio-8000-exec-1] FATAL com.test.app.appController - This is a fatal message
Hibernate: //used hibernate queries are displayed to console as needed
```

> It would be great help if someone can point out what i need to change
>   in the code. Because of improper understanding of log4j2, i guess
>   something needs to change in log4j2.properties

Please help!!
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

log4j2 switched from having a .properties file to yaml or xml. you will need to create a yaml or xml file to have log4j2 to load.

Example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE xml>
<Configuration status="WARN">
    <Appenders>
        <Console name="ConsoleAppender" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d{dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%-5p] %m%n" />
        </Console>
        <RollingFile name="myapp" fileName="${sys:catalina.base}/logs/myapp.out"
            filePattern="${sys:catalina.base}/logs/myapp-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log.gz">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d{dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%-5p] %m%n" />
            <Policies>
                <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy />
                <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="10 MB" />
            </Policies>
        </RollingFile>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Root level="TRACE">
            <AppenderRef ref="ConsoleAppender" level="INFO"/>
            <AppenderRef ref="myapp" level="INFO"/>
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

Comment: @Issac : surely a xml file will do the job, but I am looking for a .properties based solution because of my employer's restriction. And FYI - As of version 2.4, Log4j now supports configuration via properties files. refer this: https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html

Comment: Ah thank you for the update. Looking over your properties file and looking at examples, i believe you do need the root level set.